# Very slow K-means Silhouette score on feature extraction Inception Resnet V2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, k-means

I need to apply the K-means algorithm on the features extracted from the Inception Resnet V2 network. To determine the optimal K value I use the SSE (Silhouette score) criterion. The problem is that this procedure takes a long time.

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score

image_size=(150, 150, 3)
model= InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=image_size)   
​   ​
for layer in conv_base.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
​
feature = model.predict(x)
```

The very slow procedure is as follows:

```
 silhouette_coefficients = []
 scaled_features = feature.reshape(-1, 1)
 for k in range(2, 8):
    print("K:", k)
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=40)
    kmeans.fit(scaled_features)
    cluster_labels = kmeans.labels_
    score = silhouette_score(scaled_features, cluster_labels)
    silhouette_coefficients.append(score)
```

**Specifically, the slowness lies in performing the function silhouette_score.**

Any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, by it's very nature, KMeans can burn through huge chunks of time. Can you try it his way? Hopefully this methodology is faster than what you are doing now.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

from yellowbrick.cluster import SilhouetteVisualizer
from yellowbrick.datasets import load_nfl

# Load a clustering dataset
X, y = load_nfl()

# Specify the features to use for clustering
features = ['Rec', 'Yds', 'TD', 'Fmb', 'Ctch_Rate']
X = X.query('Tgt >= 20')[features]

# Instantiate the clustering model and visualizer
model = KMeans(5, random_state=42)
visualizer = SilhouetteVisualizer(model, colors='yellowbrick')

visualizer.fit(X)        # Fit the data to the visualizer
visualizer.show()        # Finalize and render the figure
```

[image]

https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/cluster/silhouette.html